# Sending HDFS file as an attachment using command line

Tags: linux, email, unix, hadoop, hdfs

I know we can send HDFS file by copying it to local and then executing :

```
/bin/mail -a "/tmp/repot.txt" -s "Email File"  abc@jfj.com
```

But is there a way to not copy to local and send an email directly from HDFS?

Answer (score 1):

Try `mpack`:

```
hadoop fs -cat /tmp/report.txt | mpack -s "Email file" /dev/stdin abc@fgh.com
```

Another option would be to use `uuencode` and pipe it to `mailx`.

Note: if you use Oozie to build your report there's [an action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.1.0/DG_EmailActionExtension.html) for email notifications